# ConfigCache::__toString() is deprecated since version 2.7

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7

After updating to Symfony 2.7 I've got deprecated notification in my profiler. Here it is:

[image]

It looks like an internal Symfony stuff. Any ideas about how to fix it or it will be fixed in next Symfony patches?

Comment: Use the... `getPath()` method instead? Have you even read the error message? This is not something that will be "fixed". It is you who needs to fix *your* code.

Comment: Yes I can read. I've meant that it's not caused by my code. It's caused by some vendor's library or internal Symfony stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue is located at the "AllowedMethodsRouterLoader" class. This might be an external bundle, so you might be able to update this bundle. If it's your own class, it's as easy as just changing it to using `->getPath()` instead of using the `ConfigCache` instance as a string.

Comment: Yep, it comes from external bundle, FOSRestBundle in my case. It should be updated as well.

Comment: Do you know which version (preferable which sha1 commit?), I cannot see any references to ConfigCache being casted to a string